# How do I change my registered xbox one location

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

I registered my xbox one to a country that i did not mean to. Now the xbox live gold subscription doesn't work. I need to change it to Russia, but I don't know how, as when I try to remove the xbox, it says that It's removed, but still pops up at my device section and doesn't go away. Any help? The xbox is kind of pointless at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

> **Important:** If you’re trying to use these steps to resolve any backward
>   compatibility account region errors, changing your account region will
>   not resolve these issues. These steps are only for when you’re moving
>   and need to change your country/region.

How to change your country/region on Xbox One:

Follow these steps to update your settings to your new country/region, and then restart your Xbox One console. When you make your first purchase in the new locale, you'll be prompted to update your billing information.

- Sign in to your Xbox One console.
- Scroll left from Home to open the guide.
- Select Settings.
- Select All Settings.
- Select System.
- Select Language & location.
- Select your new location from the list, and then select Restart now.

*Source:*
https://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/microsoft-account/update-microsoft-account-country-region